# Matplotlib string with italics and using .format()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can make italic text like this:

```
plt.title('$\it{Text}$')
plt.show()
```

I'd like to have some italic text (but not all) *and* use the .format() function, e.g.:

```
plt.title('$\it{Text}$ = {}'.format(func))
plt.show()
```

This returns `KeyError: 'Text'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`matplotlib.pyplot.title`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.title.html) accepts `style` as a keyword argument, you can pass `italic` :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text = "Stack Overflow"

plt.title(f"{text}", style= "italic")
#or plt.title("{}".format(text), style= "italic")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or if only *some* of the desired text is to be italic:

```
text = "italic" 
text2 = "something" 

plt.title(f"$\it{text}$ ~ {text2}")
```

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. Italic text is working without issue. I'd like to have some italic text and use the .format() function in the same string.

Comment: Well, that's what I did in my answer, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

I Hope I understood your question.

you can check this web if you wanna know more about format function: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-format-method/

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s=[11,22,33,44,55,66]
a=[22,33,44,22,1,34]

plt.plot(a,s)
plt.title("{}".format("GLITCH"),style="italic")
plt.show()
```